# Cleaner way to write this code [restricting characters on <input>]

Tags: javascript, html

by browsing through stackoverflow, i managed to write this code on my `<input>`

`onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[qwertyuopasdfghjklzxcvbnm ]/g, '')"`

i intended to restrict the keyboard except for letter **i**, **-**, and numbers from **0**-**9**. it works fine for my program but is there a cleaner way to write this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than specifying a set of characters to remove, because you only have a few characters to *include*, you might specify those characters instead with the use of a negative character set:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^i0-9-]/g, '')
```

You should also consider attaching the event listener properly using Javascript, rather than using an inline handler, if at all possible:

```
const input = document.querySelector(<input selector>);
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^i0-9-]/g, '');
});
```

Another possible improvement would be to use `preventDefault` instead, on the `keypress` event, rather than having the undesirable characters appear for a second and then disappear after an instant:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (!/[i0-9-]/.test(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input>
```

(though, the above will still permit those characters to be inputted via paste and click-drag and such, so you will have to resort to the `.replace` method when those events get fired)

Comment: wow, thank you for this.. i wanted to tag this +1 now but stackoverflow restricts me

Comment: maybe you could just call the .replace on the keyup event to prevent the paste/... tricks ?

Comment: @AlexvanVliet Problem with that is that then the characters inputted via manual typing would appear for a moment before being replaced. Possible, just ugly, so it's probably preferable to have separate listeners.

Comment: I meant using both the keypress you suggested and the keyup with .replace, but it doesn't help for click-drag anyway so not really usefull. Maybe using both the keypress (you gave) and the change (.replace) event